# Move numbers in a filename to the start

Tags: bash, sed, rename, awk, gnu

I have several files in a folder, with names in the form: SOMETEXT1 number SOMETEXT2.mp3, or SOMETEXT number.mp3. I want to rename these to number SOMETEXT SOMETEXT2.mp3, or number SOMETEXT.mp3. Using bash and common GNU command line tools, how would I achieve this?

Comment: Could you provide an actual example file name for each variant you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `perl-rename` (sometimes called `prename`):

```
prename -v 's/^(.+) (\d+)( .+|\.[^.]+)$/\2 \1\3/' *
```

Use `-n` to just test without renaming.

The same with `bash`:

```
re='^(.+) ([0-9]+)( .+|\.[^.]+)$'
for file in *; do
    new=$file
    if [[ "$file" =~ $re ]]; then
        new="${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
    fi
    if [[ "$new" != "$file" ]]; then
        mv -v "$file" "$new"
    fi
done
```

Comment: That works for the first variety of names, (text number text.mp3), but not the second (text number.mp3), How would I solve this? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the extension. Fixed.

Comment: Working perfectly, thankyou very much.